# Invert Objective-C @available?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

The recent `@available` addition to Objective-C can be handy but is apparently quite short-sighted..

Any app being around for more than a couple weeks will need to target e.g. multiple macOS versions.

Unfortunately the only `@available` construct for explicitly targeting **older** OS releases that appears to work (as of Xcode up to and including 12) is this cumbersome

```
  if (@available(macOS 11.0, *))
  {
     // all hunky-dory: no-op
  }
  else
  {
     // legacy work arounds
     ...
     ...
  }
```

Using just the else branch with a negation emits the dreaded *@available does not guard availability here* compiler warning..
Is there any way to simplify this ghastly code and remove the dummy no-op branch?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the preprocessor, define a macro:

```
#define ifNotAvailable(A, B) if (@available(A, B)) {} else
```

and then write your code as:

```
ifNotAvailable(macOS 11.0, *)
{
   // legacy work arounds
   ...
   ...
}
```

Whether this is less "ghastly" is in the eye of the beholder, YMMV!

Comment: Sure, arbitrary language extensions and workarounds can always be constructed using the preprocessor -
but I was looking for a universally available, built-in solution..

Comment: It is unclear what you mean "universally available". If you are wishing the macro to be available "automatically" everywhere within your Xcode project you can place it in a seperate `.h` and set the build setting *Prefix Header* to reference this file – use a project relative path. (This build setting translate to an `-include` compiler option so you can do something similar if using makefiles or the command line.)

Comment: You are encouraged to also head off to [https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) and suggest Apple add negation to both Objective-C and Swift (which doesn't have macros and so lacks Objective-C's simple workaround). Provide a cogent argument and you never know...